# click on a table row and redirect to view using jquery and laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.1

There is a table rendering some list of persons with columns like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="person">
        <td class="fname">John</td>
        <td class="lname">Doe</td>
        <td class="age">30</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and more other. When a user clicks on a row, a new view with more data about the selected preson should get loaded, using jquery. Something like:

//main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#person").click(function(){
        var lname = $(this).children("lname").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'profile',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'lname' : lname,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){

            }
        });
    }
});
```

//routes.php:

```
Route::get('profile', [
    'as' => 'profile',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@profile'
]);
```

//controller.php

```
public function profile()
{
    return view('pages.profile');
}
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".person").click(function(){
    var lname = $(this).children("lname").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'profile',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'lname' : lname,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){

        }
    });
}
```

will help hope

Comment: Please consider adding some more explanation to your answer.

Comment: this example is incomplete. The main problem is not how to send data, but how to make the profile.blade.php loaded. The dataType and success method could probably be omitted, because there is no need to bring something back, the is need to pass this lname variable to the controller and, based on it, to make  this profile.blade.php loaded with some more data about this person. This what I can't do for now.

Comment: one more comment - it is not hard to find solutions on loading pages based on some link clicking, but I haven't found any for making everything working after clicking on a table raw